# How can I set a JWT Bearer token on HTMLMediaElement .load() request

Tags: angular, typescript, html5-video, jwt, html5-audio

I have an API which is using JWT for client authentication and this is working well for normal requests, but I can't find any way to control the headers that will get sent along with the request when I use the HTMLMediaElement to load an audio file for playback.

I'm using Angular 4 with Typescript, and here's the kind of code I'm using to load my URL, which works fine if I disable the access control on the API:

```
public Load(url: string): number{
    if (!this.audioElement) {
        this.audioElement = new Audio();
        this.audioElement.autoplay = false;
        this.audioElement.preload = 'auto';
    }
    this.audioElement.src = url;
    this.audioElement.load();
    this.audioElement.pause();
    return this.audioElement.duration;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a similar requirement where I need to stream authenticated audio via a media player From an ASP.net WebApi.

You can elegantly achieve this using the HttpInterceptor which was introduced with Angular 4.3. This enables you to intercept http requests and add the bearer token:

This blog post describes how to achieve this: [Angular Authentication: Using the Http Client and Http Interceptors](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8)

```
   // src/app/auth/token.interceptor.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`
      }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When the login is success you will be getting the token. Then you need to save that token in localstorage or sessionstaorage or in a cookie or in store ngrx/store.

Code to store in localstorage.

```
 onSubmit() {
this.loginService.sendCredentials(this.model).subscribe(
  data => {
    localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))._body);
```

Now you need to send in the header of every request.

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor (private http:Http) {}

   getUserByName(username: string) {
   let url="http://localhost:8088/rest/user/userName";
   let header=new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
   'Authorization': 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem("token")});

   return this.http.post(url, username, {headers: header});
 }
}
```

Comment: I have no problem making normal requests (as stated in my question) but only when trying to use the HTMLMediaElement.load() method, which does not seem to provide any way to set custom headers.